# Can I wait for a second process review to pass from beta to production?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm working on a action on google project, I release the alpha version then the beta version.

But I need to do some changes before to deploy in production.

So my question is:
 Before deploying in production, Is there a process review again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**,

Whenever you are submitting your action to production, there will be review. No matter what changes you have done, what amount of data you have changed.